# IF AND OR statement

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am looking at two columns, `Column AL` and `Column T`

In `Column AL` I have Text that contains the word `Disable` In `Column T` I have code `ZDBC` and `others`.

I would like my if statement to work as follows.

• If Text in `AL` Contains `Disable` and column `T` contains `ZDBC` put `""` in `BF`

• Or If Text in `AL` contains `Disable` and column `T` does NOT contain `ZDBC` Put `1` in `BF`

• Or IF Text in column `AL` Does NOT contain `Disable` and does not contain `ZDBC` put `""` in `BF`

This is the formula I have put together but it does not work the way it want it to work.  What am I doing wrong? Please Help.

```
=IF(AND(OR(COUNTIF(AL54,"*Disable*"),(COUNTIF(T54,"ZBDC"))),
   (COUNTIF(AL54,"*Disable*")),((COUNTIF(T54,"<>ZBDC"))),
   (COUNTIF(AL54,"<>Disable")),((COUNTIF(T54,"<>ZBDC")))),"",1)
```

Comment: What if AL doesn't contain Disable but T **does** contain ZBDC?

Comment: Good Question I want it to add ""

Comment: Why not just check if it contains Disable and doesn't contain ZDBC then? All the rest seems to be getting ""..

Comment: You could try: `=IF(1-ISERR(FIND("Disable",AL54)),IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("ZDBC",T54)),"",1),"")`

Comment: `=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Disable",AL54)),T54<>"ZBDC"),1,"")` sounds like it would work.

Comment: Well, the one I commented can be made bit shorter, `=IF(1-ISERR(FIND("Disable",AL54)),IF(T54="ZDBC","",1),"")`

Comment: Mayukh Bhattacharya yours worked thanks so much! much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

This seemed to have worked for me and posted by person below. Much appreciated "You could try:– Mayukh Bhattacharya"

```
=IF(1-ISERR(FIND("Disable",AL54)),IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("ZDBC",T54)),"",1),"")
```

Answer (score 0):

On of the biggest helps for solving such questions is the formula evaluation, which you can find in the "Formula" ribbon, as shown here:

[image]

(The screenshot shows how it looks like after having clicked two times on the "Evaluate" button, which evaluates the underlined text in the text box.)